# How do I make an image slider with list items generated from an array

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to make an  fade-in-out slider show. Here is the sliding show code with static html code:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var slideArray = slider.getElementsByTagName("li");
var slideMax = slideArray.length - 1;
var curSlideNo = 0;
var nextSlideNo =null;
var fadeStart = false;
var curSlideLevel = 1;
var nextSlideLevel = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= slideMax; i++) {
    if (i === curSlideNo) changeOpacity(slideArray[i], 1);
    else changeOpacity(slideArray[i], 0);
}

function startSlide(dir)
{
    if (fadeStart === true) return;
    if( dir === "prev" )
    {
        nextSlideNo = curSlideNo - 1;
        if ( nextSlideNo < 0 ) nextSlideNo = slideMax;
    }
    else if( dir === "next" )
    {
        nextSlideNo = curSlideNo + 1;
        if ( nextSlideNo > slideMax ) nextSlideNo = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fadeStart = false;
        return;
    }
    fadeStart = true;
    changeOpacity(slideArray[curSlideNo], curSlideLevel);
    changeOpacity(slideArray[nextSlideNo], nextSlideLevel);
    fadeInOutAction(dir);
}

function fadeInOutAction(dir)
{
    curSlideLevel = curSlideLevel - 0.1;
    nextSlideLevel = nextSlideLevel + 0.1;
    if( curSlideLevel <= 0 )
    {
        changeOpacity(slideArray[curSlideNo], 0);
        changeOpacity(slideArray[nextSlideNo], 1);
        if(dir === "prev")
        {
            curSlideNo = curSlideNo - 1;
            if (curSlideNo < 0) curSlideNo = slideMax;
        }
        else
        {
            curSlideNo = curSlideNo + 1;
            if (curSlideNo > slideMax) curSlideNo = 0;
        }
        curSlideLevel = 1;
        nextSlideLevel = 0;
        fadeStart = false;
        return;
    }
    changeOpacity(slideArray[curSlideNo], curSlideLevel);
    changeOpacity(slideArray[nextSlideNo], nextSlideLevel);
    setTimeout(function () {
        fadeInOutAction(dir);
    }, 100);
}

function changeOpacity(obj,level)
{
    obj.style.opacity = level;
    obj.style.MozOpacity = level;
    obj.style.KhtmlOpacity = level;
    obj.style.MsFilter = "'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=" + (level * 100) + ")'";
    obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (level * 100) + ");";
}

var autoslider = setInterval( function(){startSlide('next');}, 1000);
autoslider;
```

actually, this code worked properly when html code was like that

```
   <ul id="slider">
        <li><img src="images/cafe.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/cafe2.png"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/cafe3.png"/></li>
    </ul>
```

but images from server can be changed or added.
so, I thought making it dynamic would be better.
this is added code

```
if(xhr.readyState===XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(xhr.status===200){
            var test=xhr.response.replace(/["]/g,'');
            test= test.substring(1,test.length-1);
            let test2=test.split(",");
            alert(test2);

            let lis=document.createElement("li");

            for(var i=0; i<test2.length; ++i){
                let imgNode=document.createElement("img");
                imgNode.setAttribute("src", url+test2[i]);
                lis.appendChild(imgNode);
            }
            document.getElementById("slider").appendChild(lis);

        }else{
            alert(`:'(`);
        }
    }
```

but this time, it doesn't work. 
no sliding show but the images are listed vertically. 
how could I make this sliding show? What should I edit?

Comment: This might be due to storing the `li` List Items in a `array` before anything has been dynamically created (appended) meaning `slideArray` is `undefined/NULL/0`. You want to define or store array lengths after your `xhr` call/response is complete.

Comment: You may apply class active to the first image and then load the slider.  Also to overcome what the previous comment suggests, you may have one transparent image with class active.